# How does one get the error message from an API in angular?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 6 and I have a service that attempts to create a record in the backend database by making POST request.  I implement this request in a service like so:

```
... usual imports and other Angular boiler plate omitted for brevity ...

export class SitesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  addSite(siteName){
    const url = environment.apiUrl + '/api/v1/spi/sites/';
    const body = { 'name': siteName };

    const header = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':  'application/json' });
    return this.http.post(url, body, { headers: header }).pipe(map ( res => <Site>res ));
  }
```

I make use of the above service in my component code:

```
... usual imports and Angular boiler plate omitted for brevity ...

export class SitesComponent implements OnInit {

  ... local variable declaration omitted ...

  constructor(private service: SitesService) {
       ... more unrelated code omitted ...


  addSite(siteName) {
    this.showLoader = true;
    this.service.addSite(this.siteName).subscribe(
      data => this.postSuccess(data),
      error => this.postError(error)
    );
  }

  private postError(error) {
      console.log('ERROR IS');
      console.log(error);
      ... omitted ...
  }
```

When the API responds with a BAD REQUEST 400 I know that it provides a message along with the status number 400.  As I can see it in the browsers developer's console:

[image]

but all my `postError()` method does is write to the console this:

```
ERROR IS
Bad Request
```

I would like to be able to output `name: This field is required.`.

Here is a screen shot that shows I am getting response code 400 and not 200.

[image]

**UPDATE**

It turns out someone on my team had already implemented an interceptor.  Here is its code: (I added the `console.log's`).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {LoginService} from '../login/login.service'



@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: LoginService) {}
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
          console.log('ErrirInterceptor err is:');
          console.log(err);
            if (err.status === 401) {
                // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                this.authenticationService.logout();
            }
            const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
            return throwError(error);
        }))
    }
}
```

When I access my troublesome api the console.log's output:

```
ErrirInterceptor err is:
error:
name: Array(1)
0: "This field is required."
...
```

But I still don't understand how to get that error message to my 
`SitesComponent` or `SitesService` classes.

***UPDATE II***

It turns out that the interceptor that was previously written didn't handle error responses generated by Django Generic Views so I updated it by changing this line ...

```
            const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
```

... to this:

```
            const error = err.error.message || err.error.name || err.statusText;
```

Comment: Can you see the message in the header of the answer?

Comment: Yes that is what my screen shot shows.  You can see my screen shot right?

Comment: You should create an interceptor and read the headers of the response. You will access the properties of the error object, such as error.status or error.message

Comment: I'd like to avoid having to do that as the documentation on the subject is not very clear how one does that. https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Comment: can you try adding a console log inside `this.postSuccess` and log what's being passed ? I think it may still considering it as a success. try that and run the same endpoint and see

Comment: My `postSuccess()` method is not being called.

Comment: Perfect. Good job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file with the interceptor

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';


@Injectable( {
    providedIn: 'root'
} )
export class YourInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor () { }

    intercept ( request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return next.handle( request )
            .do( ( response: HttpEvent<any> ) => {
                if ( response instanceof HttpResponse ) {
                    for ( const key of response.headers.keys() ) {
                        console.log(key); // ***** The message should come out here ******
                    }
                }
            }, ( error: any ) => {
                if ( error instanceof HttpErrorResponse ) {
                    console.error( error );
                    console.error( error.status );
                }
            } );
    }
}
```

And you import it into the main module of your application

```
import {
    YourInterceptor
} from './interceptors/.yourInterceptor';



    @NgModule( {
    declarations: [ . . . ],
    imports: [ . . . ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: YourInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [ . . . ]
} )
```

Comment: How can I make the error visible to my SitesComponent?

Comment: I think that what the api shows you is not an error object, it is a header response.
 with


for ( const key of response.headers.keys() ) {
                        console.log(key);
                    }



you can see all the header messages

Comment: It may be a response from the api and not an error. Do not treat it as a mistake, treat it as an response.

Comment: To show the responses of the api I created an alert service; Send whatever you want to the service and show it to them as a typical bootstrap style alert (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/alerts/).

Comment: Will my SitesComponent be passed the header some how?

Comment: Yes, using the service that I mentioned. An alert popup will appear on the screen.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial on this (https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/02/07/angular-7-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject)

Comment: Thanks for all your help @edu! I got figured out.  The intercepter that someone on my team had written didn't handle error responses generated by Django Generic Views.